# select recursive and order by

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion, recursive-query

I use below query to select recursive top to bottom
e.g
If `tagId` is 1 will get rows `1 > 3,4, > 5` now works fine,
but I want to know how to get result order by "Name" at each level(same parent id) get rows `1 > 4,3 > 5` ?

I treid add `ORDER BY "Name"` after `SELECT * FROM "Tag" WHERE "TagId" = $1` but not work .
and if add after `SELECT * FROM tag_tree` that will mess level become `1,4,5,3` not what I want .

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Tag"(
"TagId" SERIAL NOT NULL,
"ParentTagId" integer,
"Name" varchar,
PRIMARY KEY ("TagId")
);

TagId | ParentTagId | Name |
1     |             | a   |
2     |             | b   |
3     | 1           | b   |
4     | 1           | a   |
5     | 3           | a   |


var query = 'WITH RECURSIVE tag_tree AS (
  (
    SELECT * FROM "Tag" WHERE "TagId" = $1
  )
  UNION ALL
  SELECT child.* FROM "Tag" child
    JOIN tag_tree parent on parent."TagId" = child."ParentTagId"
)
SELECT * FROM tag_tree';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `ORDER BY` with `coalesce()`:

```
WITH RECURSIVE tag_tree AS (
  (
    SELECT * FROM "Tag" WHERE "TagId" = 1
  )
  UNION ALL
  SELECT child.* FROM "Tag" child
    JOIN tag_tree parent on parent."TagId" = child."ParentTagId"
)
SELECT * FROM tag_tree
ORDER BY coalesce("ParentTagId", 0), "Name";

 TagId | ParentTagId | Name 
-------+-------------+------
     1 |             | a
     4 |           1 | a
     3 |           1 | b
     5 |           3 | a
(4 rows)
```

For [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL):

> The COALESCE function returns the first of its arguments that is not
>   null. Null is returned only if all arguments are null. It is often
>   used to substitute a default value for null values when data is
>   retrieved for display.

In this case the function changes `null` to `0`.

Comment: what is the 0 means??